# Manipulating IE with VBA to login & book a class

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm attempting to use VBA to open a new instance of IE, go to a webpage, login, then navigate to a page where I can book my gym class, navigate to the correct class & press a 'book' button.

I am fairly well versed in simple VBA, which I have used for some time to automate excel tasks, but I have never tried to use it with IE so I'm fairly new to that side of it.
 I don't know enough about how VBA integrates with HTML, and my HTML knowledge is fairly basic.

So far, I have managed to create the code to open IE, navigate to the correct webpage, and log me in. 
From there it gets complex...

The webpage has a series of 'blocks' that can be selected for the weeks gym classes. These are updated daily, so the code would need to search for the correct date, time & class, then press the corresponding book button.

I have extensively googled the solution for the last couple of days, but can't find anything similar to what I'm looking for.

The VBA I have so far is as follows. This works well for the first part of my requirements.

```
    Sub Login_Test()
    ''This version successfully goes to puregym.com and logs into my account

    'Outstanding''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Need to select class page
    'Need to select correct date & class
    'Need to book class
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    ' open IE, navigate to the desired page and loop until fully loaded
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        my_url = "http://www.puregym.com/"

        With ie
            .Visible = True
            .navigate my_url


        Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        End With

    ' Input the userid and password
        ie.Document.getElementById("edit-email").Value = "email address"
        ie.Document.getElementById("edit-pincode").Value = "pin number"

    ' Click the Submit button
        ie.Document.getElementById("edit-submit").Click

        Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

    ' Navigate to bookings page

        With ie

        .navigate "http://www.puregym.com/members/bookings"

        End With



    End Sub
```

I may be wrong, but I believe an example of the HTML I would like to run is below. I would like to mimic the action of selecting the class and clicking the book button.
(And once I've mastered the basics of that, I'd like the VBA to compare the class name, date & time to a list I'll store in an excel range, and only book it if it's in the range. But I appreciate I need to walk before I run and all that...)

```
              <div class="day column-1" data-date="Friday 22nd January" data-    shortdate="Fri 22/1" data-index="1">
        <h2>Fri 22/1</h2>

            <div id="tt_block_53_33253" class="three columns tt_block" data-date="2016-01-22" data-time="06:15">
        <div class="timetable-class limited-availability">
                          <button class="icon-info">&nbsp;</button>
              <div class="popout">
                <span class="weekly-close">&nbsp;</span>
                <h1>FAST Tabata</h1>
                <p class="timetable-info">This class takes interval training to the next level. 20 seconds high intense work followed by 10 seconds rest for 8 rounds, sound easy?  Give this class a go, you won’t be disappointed.</p>
                                  <img src="//www.puregym.com/sites/default/files/styles/square_thumbnail/public/classes/Misc20_0.jpg?itok=mnWQFaIU" alt="Example of FAST Tabata" />
                              </div>

            <header>
              <h1>FAST Tabata</h1>
              <h2>
                06:15                                  - 06:45                                              </h2>
            </header>


                          <div class="pt-name">PT name: <strong>Lewis Pratten</strong></div>

            <span class="gym-name">Bristol Harbourside</span>

                          <div class="booking-buttons">
                      <a href="/members/class-booking/book/53/33253" class="use-ajax secondary button">Book</a>
        <span class="spaces-text">Spaces</span>
    <span class="spaces-number">1</span>

              </div>
```

Would very much appreciate any help anyone has to offer. Or advise if it would be easier in a different language? From what I've read perhaps python or java would be a better environment to do this, but I'm not familiar with either...

Answer (score 0):

To get at the Book button, you could do something like:

```
Dim links, link
        Set links = IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
        For Each link In links
        If link.innerText = "/members/class-booking/book/53/33253" Then
            link.Click
        End If
        Next link
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: How does the link.innertext work? As it doesn't seem to be a full link

Comment: Not working unfortunately.
The link, (when I open it manually) displays this 
 
'[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"puregym_skin","theme_token":"fQYzpnbZd522ytgURf23-w0dxvP_bnyCOlwifAZR4rE"}},"merge":true},{"command":"alert","text":"You are not authorized to access this page."}]'

the link to the full HTML is here [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/nye05az7u7wr3l7/PG%20Code.txt?dl=0)

Comment: link is just the variable I chose. My code is looping through every "a" tag in the HTML until it finds the one whose innerText matches what you specify. Due to security reasons, I cannot go to the link you left above or I'd offer more help. I do see in the code snippet you left that they're using AJAX though so you may have issues because of that.

Comment: @jstkrys thanks for your help so far. Can you not access the link I added at all? What would be the best way of sharing the HTML?
it is using AJAX, which I think is javascript? Do you think I'd still be able to do it?

Comment: @jstkrys try this link instead
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9hG43NbwZp0VllOMFhCWnhqV00/view?usp=sharing)